# Get imageView resource

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have been searching for hours, and cant seem to find an answer
i have a chess board and its made of 64 imageViews (8X8) and i want to move one pawn to another square, and cant seem to find the way to get the image resource (which is a png image) and set it on the empty square. i saw answers to this question using .setTag, but i am already using it to define the position of the imageView on the board (for example the tag could be "4,4")

a part of my code below:
it shows the imageView and how im setting the resource.

i have another image view and i want to get the resource from the first one and onto the other one

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_pawn_on_beige);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't do [getDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#getDrawable()) and [setBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) ? Also any reason why you are setting background rather than [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)) / [setImageDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) with ImageView?

Comment: @shriakhilc i dont think i knew about SetImageDrawable or SetImageResource, but getDrawable does not help me since i also need to compare but that will be later, i will try getDrawable thanks...

Comment: @shriakhilc  thank you, even after you answered i had some problems, but it was because i used setBackgroundResource and then used getDrawable. i had to change setBackGroundResource to setImageResource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think you need to do this, you're architecting your program incorrectly.  You should have a model that knows what every square on the board has as a piece (if any).  You should also have a function that can map a piece (or lack of a piece) to a resource id.  You should simply update that model when a move is made, then redraw any effected squares from the model.  You should not be using your views as state.  Moving to an architecture like this should both make it easier to write and to test (instead of a complicated test involving views, you're testing a function that updates the model, a function that maps the model to a resource for a given square, and a function that updates a model-  no views involved).

Comment: I do have a model, it has a two dimensional array, and it represents the board.
once a request to move a piece is requested, it goes through the model checking if the move is valid and stuff like that, then returns to the `onClick` listener function and moves the piece from one view to another.. I don't really see the problem here although I might not have understood you...

Comment: @GabiBorsky The thing you're missing is that "move a piece from one view to another" shouldn't happen.  You should just update your model, then update your views from the new state of the model.  You should not be using the state of the view in order to update the view at the new position.

Comment: so the thing is, i think its less time consuming if i update all of the views and redraw the whole board just when moving one piece.. and its better to just find the one view using its tag and then take the image from it and put it on the next.

Comment: @GabiBorsky You don't need to update all the views, just the two that are changed.  The thing is you shouldn't use the state of the view to update the other-  use the state from the model.  Doing so makes you code less complicated, easier to test, gives it a single source of truth for all data (avoids problems due to views and models going out of sync), and avoids issues where view data is unavailable or stored in a different way than you need.

Comment: i got you. im going to try to implement this now. thanks!